# Can I determine magnetic field strength from pull force?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have some samarium cobalt magnets and I need to estimate the characteristics of the magnetic field they produce.  They are spec'd to give 16 lbf of pull against an iron plate.  Is it possible to estimate the magnetic field strength as a function of distance from the magnet using that force rating?  I also, of course, know the dimensions of the magnets, but not of the plate.

Also, a secondary question: Is there a way to modify the above model to account for placing two magnets in series?

I only need a rough estimate, and I am interested in the variation with respect to the axial(pulling) direction.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are dimensions of the magnet?

Comment: @Alex Trounev, They are cylindrical 1" in diameter and 3/8" thick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an approximate force calculator at https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp which you could use to get an estimate of the magnet grade.

Alternately you could download a free modelling software package like FEMM at http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage which would allow you to fairly accurately model the specific dimensions of your steelplate and magnets.

FEMM would allow you to calculate the force of stacked multiple magnets (but you can probably also do that with the simple calculator if you scale the magnet thickness).